# Browserify Task error

Tags: npm, gulp, browserify

Just started using gulp not long ago, everything works fine before this when I'm stuck at this error. I've tried

```
//gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
browserify = require('browserify'),
source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

// Browserify task
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify(['app/scripts/app.js'], {debug:true})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
});
```

Error when running gulp browserify

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant
```

Where does this syntax error point to? I've read up some articles on the errors in package.json file too.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-connect": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.2"
  }


//browserify package.json
{
  "name": "browserify",
  "version": "13.0.0",
  "description": "browser-side require() the node way",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "browserify": "bin/cmd.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/substack/node-browserify.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "browser",
    "require",
    "commonjs",
    "commonj-esque",
    "bundle",
    "npm",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "JSONStream": "^1.0.3",
    "assert": "~1.3.0",
    "browser-pack": "^6.0.1",
    "browser-resolve": "^1.11.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "~0.1.2",
    "buffer": "^4.1.0",
    "concat-stream": "~1.5.1",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "~1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "defined": "^1.0.0",
    "deps-sort": "^2.0.0",
    "domain-browser": "~1.1.0",
    "duplexer2": "~0.1.2",
    "events": "~1.1.0",
    "glob": "^5.0.15",
    "has": "^1.0.0",
    "htmlescape": "^1.1.0",
    "stream-http": "^2.0.0",
    "https-browserify": "~0.0.0",
    "inherits": "~2.0.1",
    "insert-module-globals": "^7.0.0",
    "isarray": "0.0.1",
    "labeled-stream-splicer": "^2.0.0",
    "module-deps": "^4.0.2",
    "os-browserify": "~0.1.1",
    "parents": "^1.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "~0.0.0",
    "process": "~0.11.0",
    "punycode": "^1.3.2",
    "querystring-es3": "~0.2.0",
    "read-only-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "readable-stream": "^2.0.2",
    "resolve": "^1.1.4",
    "shasum": "^1.0.0",
    "shell-quote": "^1.4.3",
    "stream-browserify": "^2.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "~0.10.0",
    "subarg": "^1.0.0",
    "syntax-error": "^1.1.1",
    "through2": "^2.0.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "tty-browserify": "~0.0.0",
    "url": "~0.11.0",
    "util": "~0.10.1",
    "vm-browserify": "~0.0.1",
    "xtend": "^4.0.0"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "backbone": "~0.9.2",
    "browser-unpack": "^1.1.1",
    "coffee-script": "~1.10.0",
    "coffeeify": "~1.1.0",
    "es6ify": "~0.4.8",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "seq": "0.3.5",
    "tap": "^2.2.0",
    "temp": "^0.8.1",
    "through": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "James Halliday",
    "email": "mail@substack.net",
    "url": "http://substack.net"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tap test/*.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "gitHead": "5b82a2f1bc061cb47ff4aa7c702ed79fc20effa8",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#readme",
  "_id": "browserify@13.0.0",
  "_shasum": "8f223bb24ff4ee4335e6bea9671de294e43ba6a3",
  "_from": "browserify@latest",
  "_npmVersion": "2.14.7",
  "_nodeVersion": "4.2.3",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "feross",
    "email": "feross@feross.org"
  },
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "8f223bb24ff4ee4335e6bea9671de294e43ba6a3",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/browserify/-/browserify-   13.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "domenic",
      "email": "d@domenic.me"
    },
    {
      "name": "dominictarr",
      "email": "dominic.tarr@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "feross",
      "email": "feross@feross.org"
    },
    {
      "name": "jmm",
      "email": "npm-public@jessemccarthy.net"
    },
    {
      "name": "mafintosh",
      "email": "mathiasbuus@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "maxogden",
      "email": "max@maxogden.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "mellowmelon",
      "email": "palmermebane@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "substack",
      "email": "substack@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "terinjokes",
      "email": "terinjokes@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "thlorenz",
      "email": "thlorenz@gmx.de"
    },
    { 
      "name": "zertosh",
      "email": "zertosh@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {},
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify/-/browserify-13.0.0.tgz",
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!"
}
```

Comment: Show us your JSON file.

Comment: @αƞjiβ i juz realize the package files creates quite a numbers of different dependencies from the initial file i have. Is there any way to do a clean reinstall for browserify?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to run this without error by adding

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-connect": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.2"
  },
  //Tells browserify to use browserify-shim
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "./app/scripts/app.js": "$"
  }
}
```